# Is wx.StaticText thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, wxpython

For example, I'm using a `wx.StaticText` object as a counter, is it thread safe? For example:

```
class TaskFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Counter = wx.StaticText(MainPanel, id = -1, label = "0")
```

What would happen if I `GetLabel` and `SetLabel` for `self.Counter` in different threads at the same time? Would I get any trouble?

```
Result = self.Counter.GetLabel()
self.Counter.SetLabel(WhateverResult)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't thread safe. To quote this excellent [blog post](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/):

> *In the wxPython world, there are three related “threadsafe” methods. If you do not use one of these three when you go to update your user interface, then you may experience weird issues. Sometimes your GUI will work just fine. Other times, it will crash Python for no apparent reason. Thus the need for the threadsafe methods: wx.PostEvent, wx.CallAfter and wx.CallLater.*

In a nutshell, you create a receiver on a publishing object:

```
from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher
Publisher().subscribe(update_function, 'update') # Params: callback, event name
```

Then from the thread, use [`CallAfter`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#CallAfter):

```
# Will trigger 'update_function' with argument 'My message'
wx.CallAfter(Publisher().sendMessage, 'update', 'My message')
```

Regardless of this all though, if you just want to share variables between processes, use the [supported way of doing this](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Currently you are abusing a GUI toolkit to hold your variables, while you should use the built in types for that. Share these properly, and use the GUI for displaying your data.